# Android C2DM messages reach phone, forwarded to wrong app

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-c2dm

I've been messing around with C2DM and have a nice little app working perfectly in the Emulator.  I send a message from my app server to Google's C2DM servers, the message will arrive on the emulator and my app would respond appropriately.

My problem now is running the app on my smartphone (a Nexus One).  The app runs fine and registers for C2DM with Google and then forwards it's rego ID to my application server.  This is all working as expected. Problem is, when I send a message from my app server to the phone, my app never receives the message.  After some investigation I found out
that the message reaches the phone, but the C2DM subsystem seems to be forwarding the message to the Google Talk app and not MY app.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?  Can anyone give hints on what to look for to solve this?  I was assuming that if the registration messages where forwarded to my app, then everything else should be as well.

Thanks,

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now 'just works'.  For some reason after today's testing everything is just working.   The only differences are an update to Froyo that came down OTA a few weeks back but other than that the app is it's original version.

Comment: I had the same problem. (Double)Restart fixed it, but would be nice to know what the real problem is.